# How to make a JUnit Test retry in SuiteClass if it fails?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, test-suite

I have the following RetryRule class:

```
public class RetryRule implements TestRule {
    private int retryCount;

    public RetryRule(int retryCount) {
        this.retryCount = retryCount;
    }

    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return statement(base, description);
    }

    private Statement statement(final Statement base, final Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                Throwable caughtThrowable = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < retryCount; i++) {
                    try {
                        base.evaluate();
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (Throwable t) {
                        caughtThrowable = t;
                        System.err.println(description.getDisplayName() + ": run " + (i + 1) + " failed.");
                    }
                }
                System.err.println(description.getDisplayName() + ": giving up after " + retryCount + " failures.");
                if (caughtThrowable != null) {
                    throw caughtThrowable;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the following SuiteClass:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
MakeBookingTest.class,
PaymentTest.class
})

public class TestSuite {
}
```

This has two test classes.. **MakeBookingTest** and **PaymentTest**. Each of them has multiple JUnit tests.

I want them to be retried in the event of them failing. Any idea how I can achieve it?

EDIT: For a better understanding, you may use my code to give example what to add. Thanks. Appreciate it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong ... but **why**? What do you hope to gain from re-running failed tests?

Comment: Sometimes it fail because they may be flakey. But 99% of time, if i re-run... it works. A jenkins job running at midnight runs the suiteclass. So, ideally it should retry any test that fails.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I agree with GhostCat.
Flakey test code is the real issue.

But if the "*flakeyness*" is not in your code (for example a bad network connection to an external web service), then it can be useful to rerun the tests.

In that case you can do the following.

First create an interface annotation.
(This will be used to signal which tests need a retry.)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Retry {}
```

Then a `TestRule` to be applied on our test.
(This rule will check on failure if the `Retry` annotation is present)

```
public class RetryRule implements TestRule {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description method) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override 
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    base.evaluate();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Retry retry = method.getAnnotation(Retry.class);
                    if (retry != null) {
                        base.evaluate();
                    } else {
                        throw t;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Finally in our test we put everything together

```
public class RetryTest {
    private static int count = 0;

    @Rule
    public RetryRule rule = new RetryRule();

    @Test
    @Retry
    public void testToRetry() throws Exception {
        callMyFlakeyCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Question still is, how do I apply this in a SuiteClass rather than individually for each test? As I mentioned above (with example) code in my question? :)

Comment: This should work without touching your SuiteClass. Or are you trying to rerun your entire TestClass, even if only one Test in that TestClass fails? Which would not seem a very helpful behaviour.

Comment: Yes, so do I add @Rule to each test class and not touch SuiteClass? If I understand correctly? I have 55 test classes... in current context, I only included two.

Comment: Yes, add the Rule to the TestClass. And add the Retry annotation to the specific tests you want to restest in that TestClass.

Answer (score 0):

A distinct non-answer, based on the comment given:

> Sometimes it fail because they may be flakey. But 99% of time, if i re-run... it works.

In such cases, investing your time and energy in order to convince your test setup to do "re runs" ... is most likely: a bad investment.

Your problem isn't to do retries. Your **real** problem is that you have flaky tests. You invest all your time and energy in understand the **reason** why your tests aren't reliable, and then you **fix** that problem.

Anything else adds complexity to your setup for no good reason. You write special code that needs maintenance, and worse: all future readers have to understand "yeah, these tests there, we just retry them until they pass". That is the message that sooner or later people will go with.

Comment: OK, i agree with your suggestion. It makes sense to investigate why they are flakey and fix that. Nevertheless, could you give some input on how to do retries regardless? - It would be good to know how to do them in current context.

Comment: @saffik Thing is: that might take some time to sit down and try and test. For which I dont have the time right now ;-) ... if I had a good technical answer, I would have included it.

Comment: A real situation where `@Retry` is needed where flakiness is part of the code: we want to test that approximately 80% of the outputs of a method is `true` while the rest is `false`; the method itself is not deterministic, but what we want is a rough correctness(it is used for balancing of large numbers of requests to target A and B). In this case, now I adjust the range of percentage of single test to be `[0.77, 0.83]` but I found it too broad. So I want to narrow the range down, but increase the times of execution, in case it fails.

Comment: @WesternGun Thanks. That is an interesting approach. But I am wondering whether we are still talking "real" unit tests, or if this is more of a function/integration test, that happens to use the JUnit framework ;-)

Comment: Well I agree that it is more functional; I just want to state that there are cases where the result of single execution is not deterministic but statistically the method does what it should. This case is very peculiar, though. But now that we are already talking about retrying... we already know something is *peculiar/unstable*.